# Executing lines of a file with xargs, using stdout redirection

Tags: linux, xargs

I have a file that has lines that look like this:

```
"http://api.domain.com/path/to/resource?format=json" > output.xml
```

and I execute the following from my command line:

```
cat file | xargs -L 1 -I {} wget {}
```

Unhappily, the command looks lik it executes, but no file ever gets created. When I use the command:

```
cat file | xargs -L 1 -I {} echo {}
```

It prints the lines of the file *without* the double quotes. I think this may be the source of the problem. How do I get it to include them?

How can correctly I execute the `wget` command?

Comment: The initial command executes, but it won't really do what you want. As the whole line is passed as *one* argument to `wget` (or `echo`, for that matter), your redirection operator is just "lost" inside this one argument. The quotes are not the initial problem here. The question is how to solve it in an elegant way.

Comment: In your case, why not prepend each line with `wget ` and execute it?

Comment: Are you sure wget is the tool you are looking for here?  Did you mean to include the `-O` option to specify the output file?  Or maybe you want curl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quotes, redirection operators, etc. are typically parsed by your *shell* before the argv[] array is constructed. `>` is stripped away; the shell performs redirection. Quotes are stripped away; the shell performs word splitting.

With *xargs*, the entire input line goes *directly* to argv[], with the quotes and the operators being passed to wget, which has no idea what to do with them.

To parse such input files as you have, you'll need to get help from the shell, in two possible ways.

---

```
< file xargs -d '\n' -I {} sh -x -c "wget {}"
```

This way, `file` is being read *line by line* without allowing xargs to do any splitting (`-d '\n'`) and passed to the *sh* shell as part of a command line. The `-x` option to *sh* lets you see commands it executes.

---

```
while read -r line; do
    eval "wget $line"
done < file
```

Here the same is done using only builtins of the current shell – either *sh*, *bash* or compatible.